# How to add websocket support to an ingress resource in Kubernetes on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: nginx, websocket, ibm-cloud, kubernetes

**When the client tries to connect our ingress defined endpoint via a `wss://` request, the app returns 400 bad request, which according to socket.io docs is due to missing headers removed by load balancing proxies like nginx.**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/websocket-services: service-name
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.myhost.com
  rules:
    - host: www.myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service-name
              servicePort: 80
```

From the logs in the IBM provided ingress controller it seems to be a fork of this [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress). Which says that the annotation `nginx.org/websocket-services` adds support for websockets by adding directives to the generated nginx conf to pass the required headers. We have tried this as per above but to no avail.

Has anyone had any success making this annotation work? 
Any workarounds for adding to the generated nginx conf?

Any IBM people know if this functionality was intentionally removed from the fork? And if there is any way to add support for websockets in the IBM version of Kubernetes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websockets is not currently supported, we are working on adding it and I will update here when it is available.

Thank you

Edit: Websocket support is available in all regions, the annotation for it is:

```
  annotations:
    ingress.bluemix.net/websocket-services: service-name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. We can fallback to polling if sockets are not available, but doing so with more than one app instance requires [sticky sessions/session affinity](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/34bd21178915c3c533afaeb7cb8d8ebf511b18ac/examples/session-persistence/cafe-ingress-with-session-persistence.yaml). Any idea if that is currently supported?

Comment: Also any indication regarding timeframes will be very helpful for us - i.e. are you planning on adding this functionality this year, this quarter, this month, etc?

Comment: I can't commit to any given timeframe, but coding is done and we're working on getting websockets validated and released, so on the shorter end of those timeframes.  

The bad news is that sticky session support is in the same build as websockets, so switching to polling won't help you at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on the response, but websocket support is available in all regions at this time.  The annotation for it is:

ingress.bluemix.net/websocket-services: <service>

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Had to manually delete the ingress-ctl replica set as it had an older image referenced than the deployment definition for some reason. Also for anyone else wondering - to use sockets with multiple instances you will need to add sticky sessions with the annotation: 
`ingress.bluemix.net/sticky-cookie-services: serviceName=my-service name=cookie-name`

Comment: @JacobGarcowski Should `serviceName` be the websocket server or the client? Also are multiples just separated by comma?